# Advanced Backgrounds for Table Rows

Tags: tables, tcolorbox

I colorcode my table's rows for different qualities, and I reckoned it would be nice to use e.g. a striped background when multiple of these qualities should be signified, instead of defining a new color for each combination.

I have only found a solution using a picture for a single cell, but i want it for the whole row, and would, ideally, use something like the `tcolorbox` enigne and styles.

Edit: I had something like this in mind:
[image]

To further clarify: I want to color single rows like in the picture. The rows can take up different heights, but the column widths are fixed. I think embedding a png as background, if it can somehow be automatically cut to fit the height, would be the go-to solution, but then again i have no previous experience with `tikz` and wouldnt know an alternative.

A MWE stripped right from my project:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
%
\makeatletter
\setlength{\@fptop}{0pt}
\makeatother
%
\usepackage[german]{babel} %Worttrennung etc.
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %Umlautkodierung
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, booktabs, mhchem, textgreek, graphicx}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xifthen, etoolbox}
\usepackage{footnote}
%There is a \begin{savefootnotes} environment which may help in more difficult cases.

\makeindex[title=Namensreaktionen, columns=2]
\makeindex[name=kat, title=Kategorien, columns=2]
\makeindex[name=spec, title=Spezielle Zielstrukturen, columns=2]

\usepackage[top = 3cm, bottom = 3cm, left = 2cm, right = 2cm, a4paper, bindingoffset=0pt]{geometry} 

\usepackage[dvipsnames, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage[style=numeric]{biblatex}  
%\addbibresource{Msc.bib}

\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.85}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\newcommand{\NameRx}[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1\index{#1}}}
\newcommand{\tabsec}[1]{\multicolumn{4}{c}{#1\index[kat]{#1}}
\\ 
\cmidrule[1pt](lr){1-4}%
} % For formatting categories inside the table

\newcommand{\komment}[1]{\multicolumn{4}{@{\hspace{2em}}p{14cm}@{}}{\small #1} \\ \rule{0pt}{2.5ex}}
\newcommand{\kommentR}[1]{\multicolumn{4}{@{\hspace{2em}}p{14cm}@{}}{\small #1} \\ 
 & & & \\\cmidrule[1pt](lr){1-4}}
 
\newcommand{\don}[1]{\textcolor{green!35!blue!90!black}{d\textsuperscript{#1}}} 
\newcommand{\acc}[1]{\textcolor{red!80!green}{a\textsuperscript{#1}}} 
 
\begin{document}


%\line(1,0){\textwidth}
\centering
\noindent\begin{longtable}{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash%\hspace{0pt}
}p{0.26\textwidth}p{0.2\textwidth}p{0.25\textwidth}>{\tiny\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{0.1\textwidth}}\toprule %\arraybackslash is needed here to restore the original definition of \\, which is changed by \raggedright 
Name & Substrat & Reagenz &  \normalsize Verweis\\
\cmidrule[1pt](lr){1-4}
%                                               %
%                                               %
%                                               %
\tabsec{Amidsynthese}
%                                               %
%                                               %
\rowcolor{cyan!15!white} N-Acylierung & \ce{R2NH} & \ce{R^1COX} & - \\
\textalpha -chirale Amid-/Peptidsynthese & \ce{R2NH} &\ce{R^1R^2R^3C-COX},\newline
 X$\neq$Hal & - \\
\kommentR{%
Da unter den Rx. Bed. leicht enolisierbare Carbonsäurederivate ihre \textalpha -Stereoinformation ändern können, wird auf andere Reagenzien zur C.S. Aktivierung zurückgegriffen.
Eine weit verbreitete Methode ist mit DCC (Dicyclohexylcarbodiimid, \ce{(ChN=)2C}), wobei auf die intramolekulare N-Acylierung zu nicht mehr reaktionsfähigem \emph{N}-Acyl-dicyclohexylharnstoff geachtet werden muss.
Hierbei werden weitere Reagenzien (z.B. Pentafluorphenol, \emph{N}-Hydroxybenzotriazol) zur Überführung in ein reaktives gemischtes Anhydrid eingesetzt.
}%   
\end{longtable}
\clearpage

\printindex[kat]
\printindex
%\printindex[spec]
%\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please. Give a MWE...

Comment: A sketch of the expected output would also be really useful here. Do you manually evaluate thouse "qualities" or are the colors assigned automatically?

Comment: To my understandig, `tcolorbox` is not related with `tables` or `tabulars`. But you could take a look at [`nicematrix`](https://ctan.org/pkg/nicematrix) which despite its name can also draw colorful tabulars. There is no example of a striped background in its documentation, but being related with `TikZ` it should not be too difficult to do it.

Comment: Edited my question. Thanks for the suggestion, for my current project i have a very long (long)table already, but Ill take a look at it for the future. My idea was to use tcolorbox inside a row, just because I was familiar with the package, but I figure that is not achievable easily.

Comment: That's a nightmare to read... Simple is almost always better than complicated.

Answer (score 3):

I'm aware that the OP wants a solution for long (breakable) tabulars and I have no solution for that case. However, here is a solution within `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` (which constructs non breakable tabulars).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand \StripRow {m m}
  {
    \peek_remove_spaces:n
      {
        \tl_gput_right:Nx \g_nicematrix_code_before_tl
          { \__pantigny_strip_row:nnn { \arabic { iRow } } { #1 } { #2 } } 
      }
  }
\dim_zero_new:N \l_tmpc_dim
\dim_zero_new:N \l_tmpd_dim
\dim_zero_new:N \l_tmpe_dim
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__pantigny_strip_row:nnn 
  {
    \pgfpicture
    \pgf@relevantforpicturesizefalse
    \pgfpointanchor { nm - \NiceMatrixLastEnv - 1 } { center } 
    \dim_set_eq:NN \l_tmpa_dim \pgf@x
    \pgfpointanchor { nm - \NiceMatrixLastEnv - last } { center } 
    \dim_set_eq:NN \l_tmpc_dim \pgf@x
    \pgfpointanchor { nm - \NiceMatrixLastEnv - #1 } { center } 
    \dim_set_eq:NN \l_tmpd_dim \pgf@y
    \pgfpointanchor { nm - \NiceMatrixLastEnv - \int_eval:n { #1 + 1 } } { center } 
    \dim_set_eq:NN \l_tmpb_dim \pgf@y
    \pgfpathrectanglecorners { \pgfpoint \l_tmpa_dim \l_tmpb_dim } { \pgfpoint \l_tmpc_dim \l_tmpd_dim }
    \pgfsetcolor { #2 }
    \pgfusepath { clip , fill }
    \dim_step_inline:nnnn { \l_tmpa_dim - \l_tmpd_dim + \l_tmpb_dim } { 6 pt } { \l_tmpc_dim }
      {
        \pgfpathmoveto { \pgfpoint { ##1 } \l_tmpb_dim }
        \pgfpathlineto { \pgfpoint { \dim_eval:n { ##1 + 3 pt } } \l_tmpb_dim }
        \pgfpathlineto { \pgfpoint { \dim_eval:n { ##1 + 3 pt + \l_tmpd_dim - \l_tmpb_dim } } \l_tmpd_dim } 
        \pgfpathlineto { \pgfpoint { \dim_eval:n { ##1 + \l_tmpd_dim - \l_tmpb_dim } } \l_tmpd_dim } 
        \pgfpathclose  
      }
    \pgfsetcolor { #3 }
    \pgfusepathqfill
    \endpgfpicture
  }
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{@{}cp[l]{5cm}c@{}}
\toprule
Header 1 & Header 2 & Header 3 \\
\midrule
Some text & Some information & A piece on information \\
Some text & Some information & A piece on information \\
\StripRow{red!25}{black!10}
Some text & Some information on several physical lines & A piece on information \\
Some text & Some information & A piece on information \\
\bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because the PGF/Tikz nodes) are created with `remember picture` and (hence) are written on the |aux| file.

[image: Output of the first code]

With versions of `nicematrix` at least 5.19 (2021-07-23), it's possible to fill a block with a pattern of Tikz.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{@{}cp[l]{5cm}c@{}}
\toprule
Header 1 & Header 2 & Header 3 \\
\midrule
Some text & Some information & A piece on information \\
Some text & Some information & A piece on information \\
\Block[tikz={pattern= north east lines, pattern color=red!50}]{1-*}{}
Some text & Some information on several physical lines & A piece on information \\
Some text & Some information & A piece on information \\
\bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the second code]